# Acceptable use of a label and 'goto'?

Tags: c++, label, goto

I am writing a tokenizer for a compiler. I have a while loop that loops over characters and then a switch that checks for certain conditions. I then need to exit both blocks to write the token:

```
Token token;

while (peekChar() != '\0')
{
    switch (c = nextChar())
    {
        case '(':
            token = Token(TOKEN_LEFT_PAREN, currentLine);
            goto MakeToken;
        // ... every other character, some with lots of logic
    }
}

MakeToken:
    // write the token
```

Is this an acceptable use of labels, or is there a better way? I have learnt to think of labels as just terrible practice, but surely there must be uses for them (or they wouldn't be implemented in the standard?). Thanks.

Comment: The goto statement is supported only for compatibility with old code base. I do not advice neither goto statements nor labels. Using goto statements breaks the program structure and usually one goto statement is the reason for appearance of other goto statements.:)

Comment: Labels are a tool. They are neither good nor evil. Use them if they make sense, and don't use them if they don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when we want to break several scopes at once, it means that we can make sub-functions; Something like:

```
bool HandleChar(char c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case '(': {
                Token token = Token(TOKEN_LEFT_PAREN, currentLine);
                return true;
        }
        // ... every other character, some with lots of logic
    }
}
```

And then:

```
while (peekChar() != '\0')
{
   if (HandleChar(nextChar())) {
       break;
   }
}
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks - hadn't thought of that method, would certainly make the code simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the very same with `break` here, without needing to use `goto`.

The only time I found a only-slightly-revolting case of `goto` in C++ was in a complex state machine where developers took arduous care not to mess up local state.

Generally, a parser (or more specifically, a tokenizer) is the last place where I'd go for spaghetti coding -- if anything, this calls for using C++ in a more functional way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is one of very few examples when goto is accepted however you could  use a flag:

```
Token token;
bool flag = true;
while ((peekChar() != '\0') && flag)
{
    switch (c = nextChar())
    {
        case '(':
            token = Token(TOKEN_LEFT_PAREN, currentLine);
            flag = false;
        // ... every other character, some with lots of logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I somehow got into my head that a 'break' would allow the while loop to keep looping - thanks!

Comment: It would -- that's why `flag` gets set to `false`!

Comment: Yep my bad. Editing it out.

Comment: Oh, okay - good to know I'm not a complete idiot. Thanks @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ